# How to get an url contained in query string

Tags: javascript, html, url, get

I want a javascript variable  to be what is behind the ?url= in the url..

for example: The current url is

`http://mywebsite.com/test/index.html?url=http://www.google.com/`

So the variable has to be `http://www.google.com/` .

I tried this, but it doesn't work… why ?

```
    var url = document.URL ;
    var appname = url.match(?url=(.+))[1];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `location.search`

Comment: Should the URL parameter be allowed to contain GET args?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following will work for you:

```
function querystring(key) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var keys = query.split("&");
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var values = keys[i].split("=");
        if (values[0] == key) {
            return values[1];
        }
    }
}
var appname = querystring("url");
alert(appname);
```

Comment: This is way too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var regex = /\?url\=(.+)/;
var appname = regex.exec(url)[1];
```

or even simpler:

```
var appname = /\?url\=(.+)/.exec(url)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)&*.*$/)[1]; // http://www.google.com/

location     //location object
 .search     //the search part in location
 .match      //return string according to regex given
  [1]        //second result (result in parenthesis)

//--------Use in a function---------

function getQuery(txt){
    var result = location.search.match(new RegExp(txt + "=([^&]+)&*.*$"));
    return result === null ? undefined : result[1];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/J4FfZ/